# TeX Live Installation Stuck at `updmap-sys`

Tags: installing, texlive

I'm installing a minimal TeX scheme (plain + latex + a few langauge packs, configured through advanced installer) and the installation becomes stuck on `updmap-sys` reading

```
...
mktexlsr: Done.
running updmap-sys...
```

and then it gets stuck---at least it has been for the past hour or so.

Is there any reason this would happen and, more importantly, how can I continue the installation safely?

(I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with what I believe to be a 32-bit distribution of TeX Live, if that makes any difference whatsoever.)

Comment: Can you look into the process monitor and check whether it is actually doing something, or got stuck somewhere. Where strange phenomenon.

Comment: I will see if I can replicate this issue today - I ended up cancelling the operation (`^C`), and LaTeX seemed to work fine so I didn't mess further, but *something* has to be missing...

Answer (score 1):

That has happened with me for some packages before, but I run on linux.  That is, I can get around this by cancelling that package from installing and installer will move to the next package.

Is there a way to cancel one package without ending the whole operation in Windows?

If not, you could try cancelling and re-starting.  The installer should pick up where you left and may skip that package.

Comment: I don't think so.  It would be an option to simply cancel the installation and run the rest of the commands manually, if I knew what they were.

Comment: @SeanAllred if you cancel or interrupt the installing, `texlive` (ran through the terminal probably DOS command) pick ups where it left off.  It should also skip the problem package.  If you have wasted an hour and it looks to continue with no resolve, you have nothing to lose by trying.